# Why curly brackets won't put remote ssh execution in background

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, qnx

I wanted to use compound commands to execute remotely a few, quite short commands in background but I noticed that ssh waits until all commands are executed. I've tried several options and that's the result:

```
time ssh $IP 'sleep 20 >/dev/null 2>&1 &'

real    0m1,776s
user    0m0,003s
sys 0m0,003s

time ssh $IP 'sh -c " sleep 20; " >/dev/null 2>&1 &'

real    0m1,850s
user    0m0,007s
sys 0m0,000s

time ssh $IP '( sleep 20; ) >/dev/null 2>&1 &'

real    0m1,742s
user    0m0,000s
sys 0m0,007s

time ssh $IP '{ sleep 20; } >/dev/null 2>&1 &'

real    0m21,876s # <--- ssh waits until sleep is over
user    0m0,003s
sys 0m0,003s
```

Why { } blocks ssh from exiting after starting background process?

PS
Target machine runs QNX 7 with sh shell. Not bash.

Comment: Interesting. I'd like to know too. But I guess the exact version of the remote `sh` will be needed.

Comment: I guess, ssh needs to create a sh process on the remote side, and this shell  process waits until the child processes finished. What happens if you run a `nohup sleep 20 &` instead?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it. Also, what's the difference between your third and fourth cases? They seem identical to me.

Comment: @Fravadona Third one uses (). Forth one uses {;}

Comment: @user1934428 time ssh $IP "nohup sleep 20 &" also waits 20 seconds

Comment: @RenaudPacalet It's sh from qnx7

Comment: @ThomasN So, the remote runs an RTOS?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet yes

Comment: @ThomasN Hmm. This could be an important aspect. It could be that the `sh` implementation of `qnx7` is a bit different from other implementations...

Comment: @RenaudPacalet It looks like so. I've changed local shell to sh and made a test on it and it returns right away. Looks like qnx7 'thing' with sh.

Comment: QNX uses pdksh. Do you expect it to work just like GNU bash on Linux?

Comment: @StephenM.Webb Do you see any reason why it shouldn't in this case? (Thanks for pointing pdksh)

Comment: Yes. First, "bash" is not "sh" any more than "JavaScript" is not "C". Second, and full disclosure, I maintain the command-line tools at QNX and I see this kind of confusion all the time. The shells (GNU bash and pdksh) are not the same, and the OSes (Linux and QNX) are not the same. For them all to work identically is just an unreasonable expectation.

Comment: I see you don't understand my question at all. I'm not asking why it behaves differently on pdksh and bash. My question is why `{} &` behaves differently when executed using SSH? Or perchance why it doesn't behave like other commands I've mentioned in my question?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the manual:

*Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be executed in the current shell context. No subshell is created.*

And if there is no subshell, it can't run in the background, I suppose.

Comment: Maybe but with bash it does run in the background (just tested). And as per the OP, `sleep 20 >/dev/null 2>&1 &` also runs in the background while there is not subshell.

Comment: Running just `{ sleep 20; } >/dev/null 2>&1 &` go into bg on host machine and on target machine as well when invoked in interactive ssh.